# Use of local variable 'variable name' before its declaration - another issue

Tags: swift

I've looked at similar questions, but the circumstance is different.

I'm trying to pass a date variable to a different class.

The variable is declared as:

```
class DatePickerController: UIViewController {
  var defaultDate: Date!
....
```

Then, I try to read it:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(true)

          print(#function, "Incoming Date: ", defaultDate)

    ....

    }
```

What am I missing? doing incorrectly? Thanks!

UPDATE: As requested: I'm declaring the object in several places. Here's one:

```
if segue.identifier == "MasterToDate" {

            let controller = (segue.destination as! DatePickerController)      
            controller.dateType = "Birthday"
           controller.defaultDate = Date.init()

        }
```

Comment: did you set `defaultDate`?

Comment: Do you mean in another class? If so, yes.

Comment: can you show where and how you set in other class?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Change your: var defaultDate: Date! = Date.init() and then set it to your date as you are already doing. The problem is that you can't call this variable before it is initialised.

Comment: hmm. In some places, I'm setting the date to today's date. In other places, I'm using a specific date.

Comment: when you try read `defaultDate` in `viewWillAppear` it is nil or what the problem?

Comment: It won't compile.

Comment: show me error message

Comment: @Adrian, I have added an image to my question.

Comment: @ Hannes, yes I tried your suggestion, but get the same result

Comment: I think i know. try `print(#function, "Incoming Date: ", self.defaultDate)`

or better try `print(self.defaultDate)`

Comment: @DavidDelMonte remove your if !(... statement. First of all you are checking if a date is string. Second you can't check a variable before declaring it. Show me the code

Comment: @Adrian - Bingo! Thanks very much. If you want to make this an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: why the down vote please?

Comment: Where exactly is the code which is shown in the screenshot of the error message? That is *not* your `viewWillAppear` code (which should compile without problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i know. try `print(#function, "Incoming Date: ", self.defaultDate)`
or better try `print(self.defaultDate)`

In most cases, "self" is optional, but not quite the time is required. That's why I use "self" whenever we refer to the value or function in a class